# Junit Mokito Always empty values are returned

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I want to return the value of DAO using mokito but it is not working properly.

It doesn't always work.

As you can see from the code below, it sometimes returns the value I want, but sometimes it doesn't know why.

Below is an example of my code.

Example classes

```
    public Myclass {
        @Resource(name=userDao)
        UserDao userDao;

        @Resource(name=infoDao)
        InfoDao infoDao;

        public boolean checkUserService(UserVo userVo){
            int checkCnt = userDao.getUserCnt(userVo);

            InfoVo infoVo = new InfoVo();
            infoVo.setUserId(...);
            infoVo.set....
            ....
            Map<String,Object> userInfo = infoDao.getInfo(infoVo);
            return true or false;
        }
    }

public UserDao {

    public <T> int getUserCnt(T value){

    }

}

public InfoDao {
    public <T> Map<String,Object> getInfo(T vo){
    ...
    }
}
```

Test Case

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public MyclassTest{

    @Mock
    UserDao userDao ;

    @Mock
    InfoDao infoDao ;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
    }

    @Test
    public testCheckUserService()throws Exception{
        UserVo userVo =  new UserVo();
        when(userDao.getUserCnt(userVo)).thenReturn(1); // This code works normally.
        Map<String,Object> checkInfoMap = new HashMap<>();
        checkInfoMap.put("name","abc");
        InfoVo infoVo = new InfoVo();

        //I expected the result to be checkInfoMap, but the empty value will be returned.
        when(infoDao.getInfo(infoVo)).thenReturn(checkInfoMap); 

        //This code likewise always returns an empty value.
        when(infoDao.getInfo(anything())).thenReturn(checkInfoMap);

        //This code likewise always returns an empty value.
        when(infoDao.getInfo(any(InfoVo.class))).thenReturn(checkInfoMap);
   }
}
```

when(userDao.getUserCnt(userVo)).thenReturn(1); This code works, but why doesn't the code below it work?

Comment: Did you try *only* with only the last one? `when(infoDao.getInfo(any(InfoVo.class))).thenReturn(checkInfoMap);` The first may not work as `infoVo` created in tests and in the code are different

Comment: Also, by empty do you mean *null*?

Comment: no. An empty non-null value is returned.

Comment: Your code seems good. Are you sure you have included all relevant parts? Is something clearing or re-initializing `checkInfoMap`

Comment: I tried the 3 methods above, but they are all returning empty values.

Comment: When you don't stub, it doesn't have the intelligence to return an empty map. It should return a null. I think there might be something else going on. Something clearing/re-initializing the map in your test code?

Comment: It is not initializing the returned map.

Comment: @user7 I'm not sure that your most recent comment is correct.  Generally, an unstubbed call on a Mockito mock will return an empty collection or an empty map, rather than null, if the return type is some kind of collection or map.

Comment: what happens if you mock using the following?
when(infoDao.getInfo(any())).thenReturn(checkInfoMap);

Comment: My test version supports anyThing () and in case of any(), class type should be included. any(xxx.class)

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica I see. I thought it would resort to the default initial value (like done for instance variables)

Comment: Collections are different. So are wrapper types (like Integer, Double and so on) - they default to zero/false of the appropriate type, instead of null.